# Angular $http.post() reach server but not alert anything in .success

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a little problem with angular code. I use $http.post to send data to php file. That php file saves data into a database. You can see my controller below:

```
app.controller('send_data', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    $scope.data1 = "hello";
    $scope.data2 = "world";


    $scope.test_func = function() {
        data = {
            'data1' : $scope.data1,
            'data2' : $scope.data2
        };

    $http.post('server/file.php', data)
    .success(function()
    {
        alert("Success");
        console.log('success');
    })
    .error(function()
    {
      console.log('error');
    });

}
```

});

I call test_func from a button using ng-click. I can see tha data is saved into the database but no pop-up window with message "Success" appears. What is going on?

Thank you in advance,

John

Comment: Which http status code do you get? See it in the browser network console.

Comment: Try adding a .then(function(response){console.log(response)}) between the post and success lines to examine what is happening.

Comment: `success/error` are deprecated but should still be working.

Comment: It suggests that the server is responding with an error message. What does the error function say? What do your Developer Tools say in the Console and the Net(work) tabs?

Comment: console.log(status + ' - ' + data); 
is it triggered?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Firstly I have to say that I'm an newbie at angular js so I can't answer to all of your questions. Secondly I noticed that my console prints "error" so success/error is working. But I still can't understand how the data can be saved into the database.

Comment: Moreover, status code I get from network tab is "200 OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, which was a forgotten "echo 'message'" in the server side. Removed it and everything is ok now.

Thank you all for your help!

So the above code is working and you can also see the php code below:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

function mysql_con()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "admin";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //echo "Connected successfully";
    return $conn;
}


$conn = mysql_con();


$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$data1 = $request->data1;
$data2 = $request->data2;


$sql = "INSERT INTO ext_db.test (data1, data2) VALUES ('".$data1."', '".$data2."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //echo "New record created successfully";
    $data = array('success' => true);
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
//echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    $data = array('success' => false);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

$conn->close();

?>
```